# Storing PID of the script which is being called by another script

Tags: linux, shell, pid, spawn, init.d

I am a total newbie with shell scripting and have been trying write some and get my simple application running. Although I am able to start the application, I cant stop or restart it, because it is storing the PID of the script itself, while I need to store the called script's PID. Here is my script which I am running for getting the PID:

```
#!/bin/sh
JAVA_BIN=/usr/local/jdk7/jre/bin/java
test -x $JAVA_BIN || { echo "$JAVA_BIN not installed";
    if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then exit 0;
    else exit 5; fi; }

# Check for existence of needed script file
NEW_SCRIPT=/usr/local/me/myscript.sh
test -r $NEW_SCRIPT|| { echo "$NEW_SCRIPT does not exist";
    if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then exit 0;
    else exit 6; fi; }
PID_FILE=/var/run/newd.pid
USER=newuser
HOME_DIR=/usr/local/me
LOG_FILE=/var/log/newd.log
HOST_NAME=some.hostname.com


case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting newd..."

        cd ${HOME_DIR} || ( \
            echo "can't cd to homedir"; exit 1
        )

        sudo -u ${USER} ${NEW_SCRIPT} >> ${LOG_FILE} 2>&1 &

        echo "PID: "
        echo $!
        echo "\n"


        echo $! > ${PID_FILE} || (
            echo "error storing pid to ${PID_FILE}"; exit 1
        )
    ;;
stop)
    echo "Shutting down newd..."
    /bin/kill `cat ${PID_FILE}`
    ;;
restart)
    $0 stop
    sleep 5
    $0 start
    ;;
status)
    echo "Checking for service newd..."
    statc=$(curl -I http://${HOST_NAME}:8080/test/url | head -n1 | grep HTTP | awk '{print $2}')

    if [ "$statc" != "200" ]; then
            echo "down"
            exit 1
    fi

    echo "OK"
    #ps u -p `cat ${PID}`
    exit 0
    ;;
*)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
rc_exit
```

After calling this script with start command, it is showing the PID, lets say 3 for this case and ps output looks like:

```
root     3  sudo -u me /usr/local/me/myscript.sh
me       6  /bin/sh /usr/local/me/myscript.sh
me       7  PID which I want
```

as I am storing the PID as 3, then I try to stop the application, it fails , because the application which I wanna stop has 7, not 3

Anyone can help me which part of my script is ruining the expected PID?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the PID of  `sudo`, which is executing the script with another PID. So query `ps` for all children of the PID you get and, assuming `sudo` only launch one process, you will get the right PID.

Besides, have the launched script to store its own PID in the `PID_FILE`.

Comment: so i have a question about pid stuff... I have been testing and trying to find a way to kill the process properly.. and found out that, the process that i wanna kill is always PID of sudo +2.. so i can try to kill that pid+2 value? or it is just a random value depending on the available pids?

Comment: well for the +2 thing... it is not always happening... so not a good way to workaround this... i guess

Comment: No, it's not. A common hack is having the grandcild to write its PID to a file (say, /var/lib/myapp/child.pid) and read it back in the father...

Answer (score 0):

All the programs run from the command will normally be in the same process group, whose ID is the PID of the initial process. You can kill an entire process group by giving a negative PID to the `kill` command. So:

```
kill -INT -3
```

should kill everything.

Note that you have to specify the signal explicitly, because when the first argument begins with `-` it's interpreted as a signal number.

Comment: a negative pid is returning something similar to this: /bin/kill: -3: No such process

Comment: and in case i give kill -9 <PID>, it is only killing the root process, while the one that i wanna kill still remains running

Comment: It's unlikely that 3 is the actual PID of the process you want to kill. I was just using the PIDs from your example `ps` output, replace it with the correct one.